# SwaggerSchema is not working for my own objects

Tags: asp.net, api, swagger

I am creating a Web API with ASP.NET. In order to expose my database models to the user, I created Data Template Objects so I can show/hide properties from the swagger schema.

The problem is that I think this is not scalable if I want to differenciate between POST and GET methods.

Let's suppose I have a blog model where it has an identifier, a name and a creator. When I create a new blog, I want to set only the name of the blog. On the other hand, I want to read the other properties when I send a GET request.

#### Database Model

```
public class Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
    public Users Creator { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
}
```

#### Data template object

```
public class BlogDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Users Creator { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I run this code, the post request ask me to set all the creator object, plus the Blog id (which should be set by Entity Framework).

I found I can hide the identifier field by setting `[SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]`. Unfortunately, this attribute won't work for my Creator property.

That is, if I set **BlogDto** as:

```
public class BlogDto
{
    [SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]
    public Users Creator { get; set; }
}
```

The Swagger helper for POST method will be:
[image: SwaggerOutput]

I want the request body to be just:

```
{
  "name": "string"
}
```

(This problem is triggered only if the attribute SwaggerSchema is over an object created by me).

I've tried customizing the Json serializer, changing the SchemaFilter, using `[JsonIgnore]`, `[ReadOnly(true)]`. The workaround I found is creating a BlogPostDto with just `string Name { get; set; }` property, and BlogGetDto with all three properties, but I want to know if it is possible to do that with only one Dto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I could get the solution.

This issue is also reported in the swagger repository ([readOnly on nested objects](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/6537)) but I could not understand the Asp.Net equivalent.

However I tried adding `[SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]` to the class itself. I do not know why this is working, or even if it produces a problem somewhere else. Anyway this is my approach as I could not receive any other response here.

Briefly what I did was adding a new Data Template Object for users model:

```
[SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]
public class UserDto
{
    [SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Notice I put the SwaggerSchema attribute to that class. Then I can remove the attribute for the BlogDto Creator property:

```
public class BlogDto
{
    [SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public UserDto Creator { get; set; }
}
```

I think I'll have to add the attribute to every DTO I create for the project.

I am still open for further discussions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed [AnnotationsSchemaFilter](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations/AnnotationsSchemaFilter.cs) in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations

I can not find any places remove property from schema (**schema.Properties.Remove(excludedName)**)

I created another filter and use **SwaggerSchemaAttribute**  in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations

```
public class SwaggerIgnoreFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema?.Properties == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var memberList = context.Type
            .GetFields(bindingFlags).Cast<MemberInfo>()
            .Concat(context.Type.GetProperties(bindingFlags));

        var excludedList = memberList
            .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerSchemaAttribute>() != null)
            .Select(m => m.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>()?.PropertyName ?? m.Name.ToCamelCase());

        foreach (var excludedName in excludedList)
        {
            if (schema.Properties.ContainsKey(excludedName))
                schema.Properties.Remove(excludedName);
        }
    }
}

public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string ToCamelCase(this string str)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && str.Length > 1)
        {
            return char.ToLowerInvariant(str[0]) + str.Substring(1);
        }
        return str.ToLowerInvariant();
    }
}
```

and program.cs add following

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SchemaFilter<SwaggerIgnoreFilter>();
}
```

It is working perfect